# no such module 'FirebaseDatabase' when importing Firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I have been into iOS development with Xcode for a while now and I just got started with Firebase for iOS. Have setup my pods in my project and everything. However, I have searched everywhere for solution to this problem without any success. Keep getting this annoying error when I try to import 'Firebase Database'. Why can't I linked by installed pods with my project.

**PodFile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Be Happy Live Positive' do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Be Happy Live Positive
  target 'Be Happy Live PositiveTests' do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Be Happy Live PositiveUITests' do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

How do I resolve this?